# Can auto-suggest be used for TextArea field?

Tags: php, autocomplete

I am doing a site in php, needs a auto-suggest for group messaging.Clent need is to entering phone numbers separated by commas. we need to add the auto suggest functionlity for textarea.Is anybody aware of it Please help.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4329647/1592648

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518442/autocomplete-functionality-on-a-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use auto suggest on text areas. E.g. By separating words with a comma.

When entering new characters, use auto suggest Ajax calls to server (with jquery or similar tools)
The search term is the new word being typed after last comma.

When user selects a new suggestion replace the last typed chars since last comma.

There should be some plugins for jquery which do this already.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
  $.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
   $('#example').autocomplete(data);

   });

});
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329617/jquery-plugin-that-suggests-autocompletes-within-a-textarea) to get plug-in and all other information.

Also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966641/attach-jquery-autocomplete-to-a-text-field-which-is-loaded-by-ajax-call) nice example here with fix tags.

Hope, it helps you.
Thanks. !!