# Count number of lines in multiline asp:textbox using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I used to do this in a desktop app like this:

```
    private void txtSerials_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Count serials            
        SerialNumbers = Regex.Split(txtSerials.Text.Trim(), "\r\n");
        lblSerCount.Text = SerialNumbers.Length.ToString();
    }
```

How can I achieve the same in jquery?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697096/finding-number-of-lines-in-an-html-textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function translates the functionality from your C# to JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$("#txtSerials").change(function (e) {
    var serialNumbers = this.value.trim().split(/\n/);
    $("#lblSerCount").text(serialNumbers.length);
});
```

The `trim()` method is not supported in IE8 or earlier.  You can fix that by including this [JavaScript polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility):

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkthis = $("#IDofyourtextboxhere").val();
var newlines = checkthis.match(/\n/g);
var numberoflines = newlines.length;
```